# How to Shuffle an Array with Fixed Row/Column Sum?

Tags: algorithm, math, random, shuffle

I need to assign random papers to students of a class, but I have the constraints that:

1. Each student should have two papers assigned.
2. Each paper should be assigned to (*approximately*) the same number of students.

Is there an *elegant* way to generate a matrix that has this property? i.e. it is shuffled but the row and column sums are constant? As an illustration:

```
Student A   1  0  0  1  1  0 |  3
Student B   1  0  1  0  0  1 |  3
Student C   0  1  1  0  1  0 |  3
Student D   0  1  0  1  0  1 |  3
            ---------------- 
            2  2  2  2  2  2
```

I thought of first building an "initial matrix" with the right row/column sum, then randomly permuting first the rows, then the colums, **but how do I generate this initial matrix**? The problem here is that I'd be choosing between (e.g.) the following alternatives, and the fact that there are two students with the same pair of papers assigned (in the left setup) won't change through row/column shuffling:

```
INITIAL (MA):            OR (MB):
A   1  1  1  0  0  0  ||  1  1  1  0  0  0  
B   1  1  1  0  0  0  ||  0  1  1  1  0  0
C   0  0  0  1  1  1  ||  0  0  0  1  1  1
D   0  0  0  1  1  1  ||  1  0  0  0  1  1
```

I know I could come up with something quick/dirty and just tweak where necessary but it seemed like a fun exercise.

Comment: first, prove this proposition.  let C be the set of admissible matrices.  (1) if A and B in C, then there is a sequence of row/column permutation matrices P1...Pn where A = P1 P2 ... Pn B.  (2) if B in C, then for any sequence of row/col permutation matrices P1...Pn, A = P1 P2 ... Pn B is also in C.  From this, you know that it doesn't matter what your initial matrix is.  Simply make it n-diagonal with a corner triangle of 1s as you have as example.

Comment: That sounds plausible but what do you mean by "row/column permutation matrices"? It seems to me there is no way to go from MA to MB in my post by just shuffling the rows and columns. I.e. there are always going to be two rows with 1's in identical places. Am I wrong in this?

Comment: *It seems to me there is no way to go from MA to MB in my post by just shuffling the rows and columns*.  **That means you haven't stared at it for long enough**.  You can use some form of Gaussian elimination.  For your example, use C = [1 0 0 0; 1 0 0 0;0 0 1 0; 0 0 1 0], then C * B = A.

Comment: You're right! But your **C** is *not a permutation matrix* because it doesn't have a 1 in each column? Does it still preserve row/column sums? (I.e. you are "deleting" row 2 and 4 from **MB**). It seems that under pure permutation matrices that **MA** and **MB** are in different 'groups'?

Comment: that's because A and B aren't square.

Comment: I don't think it is, the permutation matrix permutes the rows or columns of the matrix it is multiplied with (which does not need to be square), but for that it needs to have a 1 in each row and column. I'm sorry to say this: but read the wikipedia for "permutation matrix".

Comment: in your original post, all matrices were square.  after the edit, matrices were made non-square, so the proposition on longer holds.  after your modification, row sums and col sums are different.  the transformations can be extended from permutation to something else to account for this.  can you come up with it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23715/discussion-between-noio-and-thang)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make permutations, what about:

- Chose randomly a student, say student 1
- For this student, chose a random paper he has, say paper A
- Chose randomly another student
- For this student, chose a random paper he has, say paper B (different from A)
- Give paper B to student 1 and paper A to student 2.

That way, you preserve both the number of different papers and the number of papers per student. Indeed, both students give one paper and receive one back. Moreover, no paper is created nor deleted.

In term of table, it means finding two pairs of indices(i1,i2) and (j1,j2) such that A(i1,j1) = 1, A(i2,j2)=1, A(i1,j2)=0 and A(i2,j1)=0 and changing the 0s for 1s and the 1s for 0s => The sums of the rows and columns do not change.

Remark 1: If you do not want to proceed by permutations, you can simply put in a vector all the paper (put 2 times paper A, 2 times paper B,...). Then, random shuffle the vector and attribute the k first to the first student, the k next ones to student 2, ... However, you can end with a student having several times the same paper. In this case, make some permutations starting with the surnumerary papers.

Comment: Your first solution doesn't seem to guarantee anything about the column or row sums. It seems like your second solution allows a student to have the *same paper twice*, which is not desirable.

Comment: @Noio: I changed my answer, hope it is more clear now. For the second solution, sorry, I had not understood that multiple papers were not allowed. I made a comment on that.

Comment: Ah, that sounds good. Under that operation ("swapping"), I think that **MA** and **MB** from the question *are* equivalent. That would mean the initial condition is irrelevant, so I can just pick anything and then proceed to do many many swaps.

Comment: Yes, there is just one permutation between MA and MB (i1=2, i2=4, j1=1, j2=4)

Comment: @Noio: Does this answer satisfy your needs? Is something missing?

Comment: Well I was hoping that perhaps there would be another way. Though your method does achieve what I sought, the "problem" is that you have no way of knowing how many swaps to perform to introduce enough randomness, and that the swap operation depends on the current state of the matrix. What I ended up implementing (just for simplicity's sake) is row/column shuffling, with the initial rows being all n-choose-k combinations, similar to what @larsmans mentioned. So I'm in doubt as to which answer to accept, and I was hoping for an even more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the initial matrix as follows (pseudo-Python syntax):

```
column_sum = [0] * n_students

for i in range(n_students):
    if column_sum[i] < max_allowed:
        for j in range(i + 1, n_students):
            if column_sum[j] < max_allowed:
                generate_row_with_ones_at(i, j)
                column_sum[i] += 1
                column_sum[j] += 1

                if n_rows == n_wanted:
                    return
```

This is a straightforward iteration over all *n* choose 2 distinct rows, but with the constraint on column sums enforced as early as possible.